# Add an Order column to an existing table that contains data with SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Recently I was working on a project that needs to add a column to sort existing records. To clarify the subject, I will give a small example. Suppose we have a table to store the names of Corona vaccine injection centers and another table to register the people who come to each of these centers. After collecting the data, we come to the conclusion that to manage the order of turns, we must add a "Order" column to Person table. How can I do this by writing a query without losing the data collected so far?

Here is the table of centers:

[image]

And this is the table of person:

[image]

And what I expect is something like this:

[image]

PS: I use SQL to create tables and store data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a *view* for this with the Order column created on the fly.

Is it an order or a *sequence*? I'd avoid "order" as it's a reserved word.

```
Create view PersonSequence as

Select Id, Name, CentreId,
  row_number() over (partition by CentreId order by Id) as Sequence
from Person
```

To update an existing table you could do

```
alter table Person add Seq int;

with u as (
  Select *,
  row_number() over (partition by CentreId order by Id) as rn
  from Person
)
update u
set seq=rn;
```

See [Fiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22214c252ff3b96324a7811013baeb99)

Comment: thanks, it's worked, but I don't want to create a view for this, for some reason i need to alter the main table, can you help for this too?

Comment: and by "order" i mean "sequence", Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well if you have to you could add a column and just use the query above to update it?

Answer (score 1):

```
select Id,
       Name,
       CenterID,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CenterId order by Id) as Order
from person
```